# How to remove folder in '/private/var/root/Android'?

Tags: mac, macos, android, ios

Please help me remove folder '/private/var/root/Android' on my Mac.
I make sudo rm -rf /private/var/root/Library/Android/ but nothing happens.

Any ideas, I will be very grateful.

Comment: Can you please run `ls -ld /private/var/root/Library/Android /private/var/root/Library` and copy/paste the result into your question (there is an edit link at the bottom of it)?

Comment: Ah, and actually, do you want to remove `/private/var/root/Android` or `/private/var/root/Library/Android/`? Please check the path names

Comment: The path names: /private/var/root/Library/Android/

Comment: Result for 1 question: drwxr-xr-x  3 root  wheel  102 Mar 29 16:07 /private/var/root/Library/Android

Comment: Run `sudo rm -r  /private/var/root/Library/Android/` then and add the error message you get to the question (the `-f` you are using suppresses any errors).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those paths don't match. To remove a folder, you need to provide the exact path to the folder:

```
sudo rm -rf /private/var/root/Android
```